# How to access a variable outside helper function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code on a view:

```
@{
    string x = "whatever";
}
```

and then I'm trying to define a helper function:

```
@helper MyHelper() { 
    <div class="whatever" @x>
    </div>
}
```

but, apparently, @x "does not exist in the current context"... how do I access it?

Answer (score 0):

Set it as parameter to MyHelper():

```
@helper MyHelper(string x) {...
```

Something useful here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor

Comment: that doesn't answer the question.  neither does the link provided